# Why is this oneliner giving me syntax error?

Tags: python

```
import random;  while True: print (random.randrange (1, 100 + 1, 2))
```

I'm trying to generate infinite amount of odd numbers with range from 1 - 100

Comment: A while statement is a compound statement. You can only use semicolon to separate simple statements .

Comment: `import itertools, random ; [_ for _ in itertools.count() if print(random.randrange (1, 100 + 1, 2))]`
will do the trick

Comment: Replace `;` with a literal newline.

Comment: I like Python, but it's really not great for one-liners.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons cannot be used to join arbitrary statements, only "small" statements:

```
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | nonlocal_stmt | assert_stmt)
```

A small statement is (roughly speaking) any statement that doesn't involve indentation.

Instead, you need to separate the import and the loop with a literal newline. If your shell supports it, you can use

```
python -c $'import random\nwhile ...'
```

Otherwise, you need to relax your definition of 'one-liner':

```
python -c 'import random
while ...
'
```